# How to hide/show by div with class on toggle switch

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, class

I have to implement a toggle switch where if you click the first time a div with a specific class will be hidden. If you click it again the div should be shown again. Until now i tried to solve it with a small jquery script. I have to tell, that I'am not a jquery expert. So if you have better solutions with other script language i'am open for you inputs ;-)

The hide part works perfectly. Only the part of showing the div again after a second click doesn't work.

Thats the code I have until now:

**html:**

```
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round hide-off"></a></span></label>
<br><br>
<div class="hideme">
  Please hide me, but bring me back later ;-)
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".hide-off").click(function(){
    $(".hideme").hide();
    $(this).removeClass('hide-off');
    $(this).addClass('hide-on');
  });

  $(".hide-on").click(function(){
    $(".hideme").show();
    $(this).removeClass('hide-on');
    $(this).addClass('hide-off');
  });

});
```

Find the whole code including CSS/style... here: https://jsfiddle.net/r9newfmb/1/

Comment: jQuery has a special toggle function that you should try, [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: can you add your css?

Comment: And can you check your html some tags didnt closed properly

Comment: Your  * $(".hide-on").click* is not triggering have u checked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check for the checkbox status.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".switch input").on("change", function(e) {
    const isOn = e.currentTarget.checked;

    if (isOn) {
        $(".hideme").hide();
    } else {
        $(".hideme").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Lin here: https://jsfiddle.net/o8ruye1k/3/

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do it using jQuery toggle function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".toggle-switch").click(function(){
  $(".hideme").toggle();
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round toggle-switch"></a></span></label>
<br><br>
<div class="hideme">
  Please hide me, but bring me back later ;-)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with javascript you can eaisly toggle the css class.

```js
let cb = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
cb[0].addEventListener("click",function(e) { 
        let myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("hideme");
        myDivs[0].classList.toggle("hide");
    });
```

```css
.hide{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>
<div class="hideme">
  Please hide me, but bring me back later ;-)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, vanilla JS.

```
<button data-toggle="">Hide/Show</button>

<p data-toggle-this="">Hello</p>
```

I think pure/vanilla JS will be easier.

```
document.querySelector('[data-toggle]').addEventListener('click', (item) => {
 const toggle = document.querySelector('[data-toggle-this]')
 const isVisible = toggle.classList.contains('show') // Here we check that our element has class show
 if (isVisible) {
  toggle.classList.remove('show') // Here we remove class if it is
 } else {
  toggle.classList.add('show') // Here we added class
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

More likely your code, but your 'hide-on' function is not working

```js
$(document).on('click', '.hide-off', function () {
  $('.hideme').hide();
  $(this).removeClass('hide-off');
  $(this).addClass('hide-on');
})

$(document).on('click', '.hide-on', function () {
  $('.hideme').show();
  $(this).removeClass('hide-on');
  $(this).addClass('hide-off');
})
```

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }
  
  .switch input { 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  /* Rounded sliders */
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

/*END OF TOGGLE SWITCH*/



.hideme {
  padding:20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round hide-off"></span></label>
<br><br>
<div class="hideme">
  Please hide me, but bring me back later ;-)
</div>
```